# Error:The serializable class practice does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long

Tags: java, vscode

cuando quiero ejecutar este codigo en Visual Studio Code...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class practice extends JFrame implements ChangeListener
{

  private JCheckBox chek1, chek2, chek3;

  public practice()
  {
    setLayout(null);

    chek1 = new JCheckBox("Ingles");
    chek1.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30);
    chek1.addChangeListener(this);
    add(chek1);

    chek2 = new JCheckBox("Frances");
    chek2.setBounds(10, 50, 150, 30);
    chek2.addChangeListener(this);
    add(chek2);

    chek3 = new JCheckBox("Aleman");
    chek3.setBounds(10, 90, 150, 30);
    chek3.addChangeListener(this);
    add(chek3);
  }
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
  {
    String cad = "";

    if (chek1.isSelected() == true) {
    cad = cad + "Ingles-";

    }
    if (chek2.isSelected() == true) {
      cad = cad + "Frances-";

    }
    if (chek3.isSelected() == true) {
      cad = cad + "Aleman-";

    }
    setTitle(cad);
  }
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    practice ventana = new practice();
    ventana.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 200);
    ventana.setVisible(true);
    ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ventana.setResizable(false);
   } 
}
```

me sale el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer se debe a esto..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Copie todo el codigo y cree un archivo nuevo en Sublime text 3 cuando guardo y compilo si funciona...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria saber a que se debe ese error y como solucionarlo en VScode ya que me gusta ese editor y no quiero dejar de usarlo para mi practica por ese error.
Muchas gracias de antemano :)

No he creado un JAVA HOME ni CLASS PATH, de hecho mi jdk esta agregado en el archivo .bashrc y en el .zshrc y cuando ejecuto java --version en la terminal funciona bien(no se como configurar java home y class path)...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu Visualk studio code está mal configurado, de alguna manera no apunta a tu JDK, te recomiendo agregar a la pregunta lo referente a tu JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH y carpeta de instalación de tu JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione al parecer si tenia mal configurado el JDK Ruslan Lopez 
Esto fue lo que hice...
Presionando shift + p abri preferencias:abrir configuracion(JSON)
y modifique el archivo agregando la ruta de mi JDK a JAVA_HOME de esta manera...

("JAVA_HOME":"ruta/de/la/carpeta/bin de su JDK",)

Luego reiniciar VScode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego Abri un carpeta nueva en VScode, copie el codigo, guarde el archivo con otro nombre de archivo,compile, ejecute y parece que ahora si funciona. :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te recomiendo aceptar tu propia respuesta :)